# ng-select multi select checkbox in angular 7

Tags: html, angular, typescript

what I want to do is when I check an item the div of that item appears

for example if I select `Crédit bancaire`  and `Compte courant associé`.
the two divs corresponding to these items are displayed

Here is the example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d163sn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a simple workaround, try changing `bindValue` from `id` to `name`

and change this code

```
<div>
    <div *ngIf=" selected == 1">Crédit bancaire</div>
    <div *ngIf=" selected == 2">Compte courant Associe</div>
    <div *ngIf=" selected == 3">Fonds Propres</div>
</div>
```

to this

```
<div *ngFor="let item of selected | keyvalue">
      <h1>{{item.value}}</h1>
</div>
```

[image]

the idea is to store that object to an iterable object, but keep in mind we need to use `keyValue` pipe to make it work with `ngFor`.